# How do I access device using hostname that is hosting an access point?

Tags: dns, hostname, access-point, host-name-resolution

I have an embedded linux device hosting an access point, I set it up like this:

```
sudo apt install dnsmasq-base -y
nmcli connection add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name access_point autoconnect yes ssid my_ssid
nmcli connection modify access_point 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
nmcli connection modify access_point wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli connection modify access_point wifi-sec.psk "my_password"
nmcli connection up access_point
```

I am able to connect to the access point and get an IP address. I am then able to ssh to the device hosting the access point using IP like:

```
ssh user@IP
```

I want to host a small web server on the embedded device that devices can access while connected to the access point. I would like to be able to hit the server with a hostname rather than an IP.

Is this possible with only making changes to the embedded device, I don't want each device that connects to the access point to have to put an entry in their hosts file for example.

Comment: Not really. The network devices only understand IP and MAC addresses, hostnames are only for us humans. So you need to set up a name service that can translate the humanly readable URL to a network-understandable IP address.

Comment: Is there somewhere that details how to do this, I'm struggling to find anything related to the access point. I thought it would be easier with the AP as DNS requests go to the device hosting the AP, I. was hoping I could just put an entry "somewhere" that resolves a specific domain to the device hosting the AP.

Comment: Step-by-step instructions on setting up your own internal DNS server can be found in the internet.